# VBA CopySheetsFromClosedWorkbook but overwrite (update) existing sheets with new values

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

What I am trying to do is to have MACRO which will copy the data sheets from external workbook and copy (same data) them into my active workbook. I am getting unfortunately doubled sheets at the end of my active wb.,which I have to delete manually. I need a way to achieve it with VBA but to preserve the same name of sheets, but only data to be copied!

This is a code I am trying to use:

```
Public Sub CopySheetFromClosedWorkbook()

Dim sourceBook As Workbook
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set sourceBook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\MV\Desktop\1234\1234_CustomerVersion.xlsx")
sourceBook.Sheets("1234 - customer's form").Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
On Error Resume Next
ActiveSheet.Name = "1234 - customer's form"
On Error GoTo 0
sourceBook.Sheets("abcd").Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
On Error Resume Next
ActiveSheet.Name = "abcd"
On Error GoTo 0
sourceBook.Close

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

This is simplified version of the code that I am using, getting copied sheets which is not my goal.

```
Public Sub CopySheetFromClosedWorkbook()

Dim sourceBook As Workbook


Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set sourceBook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\MV\Desktop\1234\1234_CustomerVersion.xlsx")

sourceBook.Sheets("1234 - customer's form").Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)

sourceBook.Sheets("abcd").Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)

sourceBook.Close

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub

Comment: Not quite sure what you need here, is it just a way to avoid manually deleting the sheets? If so just delete them with e.g. `Sheets("1234 - customer's form").Delete`

Comment: @Absinthe I need to rewrite (and update with new data) sheets on my active workbook with a data that are on external workbook.

Comment: Probably want to re-word your question then, specifically regarding how to copy the data across and also show what you've attempted so far.

Comment: @Absinthe Check the edited version, second code is what I temporary using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Copy Sheets From Workbook to Workbook

The following will delete the worksheets with the names contained in the array `shNames` (if they exist) in the Target Workbook (`tgt`) and will then copy the same sheets from the Source Workbook (`src`) (if they exist) to the Target Workbook (`tgt`).

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopySheetFromClosedWorkbook()

    Const FilePath As String = _
      "C:\Users\MV\Desktop\1234\1234_CustomerVersion.xlsx"
    Dim shNames As Variant: shNames = Array("1234 - customer's form", "abcd")
    Dim tgt As Workbook: Set tgt = ThisWorkbook
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim src As Workbook: Set src = Workbooks.Open(FilePath)
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, i As Long
    
    For i = 0 To UBound(shNames)
        ' Check if Target Worksheet exists.
        On Error Resume Next
        Set ws = tgt.Worksheets(shNames(i))
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            ws.Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
        ' Check if Source Worksheet exists.
        On Error Resume Next
        Set ws = src.Sheets(shNames(i))
        If Err.Number = 0 Then ws.Copy After:=tgt.Sheets(tgt.Sheets.Count)
    Next i
    
    src.Close False
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

EDIT:

This one will copy the `Used Range` from the Source to the Target Worksheets.

```
Sub CopySheetFromClosedWorkbook2()

    Const FilePath As String = _
      "C:\Users\MV\Desktop\1234\1234_CustomerVersion.xlsx"
    Dim shNames As Variant: shNames = Array("1234 - customer's form", "abcd")
    Dim tgt As Workbook: Set tgt = ThisWorkbook
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim src As Workbook: Set src = Workbooks.Open(FilePath)
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range, i As Long
    
    For i = 0 To UBound(shNames)
        On Error Resume Next
        Set ws = src.Sheets(shNames(i))
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            tgt.Worksheets(shNames(i)).Cells.Clear
            Set rng = ws.UsedRange
            rng.Copy tgt.Worksheets(shNames(i)).Range(rng.Address)
        End If
    Next i
    
    src.Close False
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes!! Exactly this man!  Two last questions, 1) how to put those "new" sheets at the beginning because from this code they are at the end?! 2) connected to the first question, I lost my reference to the fields even though it is the same sheet name. any idea?
YOu helped me a lot!

Comment: 1. You turn around the names in the array `shNames` and use `Before` instead of `After` and `1`.instead of `tgt.Sheets.Count`. 2. I do not understand the second question.

Comment: 1) Works!  2) What I ment is after I inserted those two sheets my reference cells on another sheets got an errors =#REF!M1 - they are/were dependent on those two sheets.

Comment: One more thing, I realized that deleting Sheets wasn't clever idea, because of getting an error with referencing cells on other sheets. Someone replied me with this on this code: "Don't delete ws, but clear it instead and paste values over the top"!

Comment: sorry didn't see your reply from yesterday! Seems to be good, tomorrow I will reply it once when check it in the office! Thx!

Comment: Sorry for spamming again, question, what can affect that some of objects are a bit displaced when copy/pasted using this macro? For instance I got Logo or some control boxes and when pasted on active workbook they are not centered. Is it because of Excel versions maybe (using 2016 but originally doc is made in 2013), or something else?

Comment: Hi, I know it is an old post, and it is actually solved, but I bumped on funny situation where I have some WBs that are having different sheet names (but the content is the same), our "experienced" people changed sheets for some documents...and now I have to change in the code sheet names...is there a way to make it dynamic or that it recognises the Sheets name automatically? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It has been a long time, surely the code could be improved. You should ask another question with all the details (the exact names that are different) and add the code you're using. Also, you can post the link in these comments to make sure I can find it. But others might also come up with a solution.